# two link tag on CSS - priority

Tags: css, tags

this is my first time in stackoverflow website and I have a question regarding CSS priority of **two link tag** and the two files contains same class variable name. Which class variabel will it pick up. Thanks in advance.

here is the structure of the code.

```
<link href = "../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" >
<link href = "example-fixed-layout.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
```

Answer (score 2):

The last css rule that appears, if it's the same specificity of the other one, will be the one that applies. Show the rule in question if you want a more specific answer than that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the selectors are identical in both files, then the class defined in `example-fixed-layout.css` will be used.

The 'C' in CSS stands for cascading...

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same class and use same rule declaration always last one go to max priority. If you use the !important rule, it will override ALL previous styling rules for that specific property on that element!

1.
2.

Suppose the first CSS file bootstrap.css has a class called .nav-header. And declare some property like:

```
.nav-header{
  background:#f9f9f9 !important;
  color:#000;
}
```

and Second CSS file has the same class and write some rules and property like:

```
 .nav-header{
      background:#f9f9f9;
      color:#000;
    }
```

Although there was supposed to be the loading of CSS class data from the second file due to the use of important property the data will be loaded from the first file